# Google Finace change a number to negative if another column is marked sell

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance, google-finance-api

Currently working on making a portfolio tracker.

im looking probably for a if statement that will change my Quantity of shares held to a negative if another column is labeled as 'SELL'. You can see from the image provided, the right column is what im looking for.

[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

simple `IF` switch:

```
=IF(B2="sell"; GOOGLEFINANCE()*-1; GOOGLEFINANCE())
```